# adding style to a javascript form error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using an hubspot form in an external website:

I am unable to change the css attributes of the javascript body. My code is as below:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://js.hsforms.net/forms/current.js"></script>
<script>
    hbspt.forms.create({ 
        portalId: '47773xx3',
        formId: 'xxxxxx',
    });
</script>
```

How do i add style to this? e.g.: background to it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right click on it -> Inspect element. Then check what class / ID it has, and add styles for this class / ID in your page or in an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function below formId, if for instance you want to change background-color:

```
formData: {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background-color = "...";
}
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, apparently this code is wrong. Try to give a look at this link, I think it can be useful.
http://help.hubspot.com/articles/KCS_Article/Forms/How-do-I-style-my-embedded-form

Comment: It's `style.backgroundColor`, not `style.background-color`. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp).

Comment: <script>
  hbspt.forms.create({ 
    portalId: '477733',
    formId: 'xxxxxxxx',
    });
  formData: {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background-color = "blue";
}
</script>